# Using Node.js to create bucket and push object, extra blank file created?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, express

I'm using an ExpressJS (based on Node.js) to push up to Amazon S3. I'm new to this so, I copied the example Amazon gave, and I see that in the S3 Management Console, there's an extra file that's the same name as the bucket I'm creating. What part of my code made this?

```
// Create a bucket using bound parameters and put something in it.
var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'test_bucket/sub_bucket'}});
s3bucket.createBucket(function() {
    var data = {Key: 'result', Body: 'Hello!'};
    s3bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
            res.write("Successfully uploaded data to test_bucket/sub_bucket/");
            res.end()
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'test_bucket/sub_bucket'}});` will create an extra file. Take out the params in the parentheses. I found out that [Amazon's quick start guide](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/) example creates an extra file. This way is the correct way to do it.

```
// Create a bucket using bound parameters and put something in it.
var s3bucket = new AWS.S3();
s3bucket.createBucket(function() {
    var params = {Bucket: 'bucket/sub-bucket', Key: 'file_name1', Body: 'Hello!'};
    s3bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
            res.write("Successfully uploaded data to bucket/sub-bucket/");
            res.end()
        }
    });
});
```